# Using both a firewall and vpn on android

Tags: vpn

Is there a way to use both a firewall and a vpn app on android. I have tried allowing the vpn through the firewall but one invaraibly goes off when I start the other. Is there some way around this -- to establish two tunnels at the same time.

Comment: You would also need to clarify what kind of firewall you are using. A VPN-based "no-root" one, or one that requires root like AFWall+.

Answer (score 0):

The firewall not stablish a tunnel, this only open or close ports, you can use but you need not close ports of VPN and maybe network of VPN can use other proxy if for example is you home network and you use firewall on your home router. You can use firewall and VPN, both, but is important that firewall not close ports of your VPN.

Comment: FYI: Lots of Android "firewalls" are actually a VPN routing the requests.

Comment: but they don't provide the encryption. Is there any way to establish a tunnel within a tunnel. Or do you know any firewalls that also encrypt.

Answer (score 0):

No, is isn't possible on Android to do this. But I would suggest setting up your firewall policy on the other endpoint of the VPN tunnel (the remote end) which will have the same effect as a local firewall policy.

I suspect you use the VPN to tunnel home? In your VPN router or home firewall that you tunnel to, there you can put rules which traffic are allowed to exit from VPN interface to internet.

Comment: I need a local firewall policy. Are you sure it wouldn't be possible even with a custom android rom